# Problem in VS Code to target Virtual Environment (.venv) in my workspace using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv, virtual-environment

I followed the guide [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) on "**Getting Started with Python in VS Code**" but encountered a problem when trying to run:

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

To overcome this problem, I ran the following code and it works:

```
"c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python playground\scratch project 1\.venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install matplotlib
```

**My goal** is to let VS Code target my workspace project virtual environment to install  libraries each time I want to install a package using a command simple as:

```
python -m pip install [PACKAGE-NAME]
```

[image]

I already have the Interpreter selected as:

[image]

Project Structure:

[image]

Comment: You need to run `activate.bat` to activate the environment although normally VSCode does it automatically.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie in programming, so can you please explain how I do that?

Comment: You just need to navigate to `venv` directory and then type `activate.bat` and then your virtual environment will be active.

Comment: Hey your activating.bat work and it solved my problem. @pavel 
Could you please explain what activate.bat and deactivate.bat is?

Comment: `activate.bat` basically sets some user-level variables so that while the python session is in progress programs like pip would install modules into `venv` folder (or whatever you name it). If you want to change virtual environment you can deactivate one and activate another.